# Boost C++ versioning issue

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm compiling a C++ code from imported project (Project created by someone else). I got this error:

```
libboost_system.so.5 needed by [...] not found
libboost_thread-mt.so.5 needed by [...] not found
```

It is clear that the compiler/linker looks for this libraries and was not able to found them. On my system, doing `ls -l /usr/lib64/libboost_*`, it shows:

```
/usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_date_time.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
```

it seems that Boost library exist on the system but version not match. Normally, for the Linux systems, the library version number is in the name of the library itself, so I assume that my linker looks for version 5. Surprisingly, the version **5** of Boost C++ lib does not exist according to the official [web site](http://www.boost.org/users/download/), the last version is **1.63.0**.

Anyone have an idea for this game of versions?
Thanks

Comment: The `.so.5` looks suspicious.  You may need to fix that Makefile.  In general, compiling all required components from source is all it takes.  Your version 1.53.0 should be fine.

Comment: Is this a `cmake` project or `autotols` or some IDE? you probably need to change the names of boost dependencies in some specific file (CMakeLists.txt for `cmake` or a configure.in file for `autotools` or project properties in your IDE)

Comment: It is `qmake`. Ii is a Qt project with .pro. I will see what I can change there

Comment: Normally, you don't have to specify any versions (that is version tags in library names) in the build settings. You may need to test for a minimal version of Boost but as far as linking goes you specify `-lboost_system` without any version. In the filesystem, there should be `libboost_system.so`, which is typically a link to a versioned actual library, like `libboost_system.so.1.53.0`. That link is normally provided by a -dev/-develop package that must be installed to build your code. So if you have to spell library versions in the build scripts you're most likely doing something wrong.